# Chat background for this site is broken

Tags: feature-request, chat

When you access chat in askubuntu, this is what happens:
[image]

Perhaps the background of the page should also be orange? Or the logo text turns black and the background white? I mean an orange box in a white page looks weird.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything broken in your screenshot, can you circle what is broken? Otherwise it looks normal.

Comment: A feature request closed as primarily opinion-based? Really? I tought we had a democracy :)

Comment: Sorry, missed that!  VTRO!